# Show that for each triple there is a unique solution of the vibration equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that for each triple $(t_0, x_0, v_0) ∈ R^3$ und $ω ∈ [0,∞)$
there is a unique solution of the vibration equation
$$\ddot{x}(t) = −ω^2x(t)$$
with the initial values of $x(t_0) = x_0$ und $\dot{x}(t_0) = v_0$.
This is given by
$$x(t) = x_0 \cos (ω(t − t_0))+\frac{v_0}{ω}\sin(ω(t − t_0)).$$
How do I show that?

I have no clue what to do. Please give me a hint...

Comment: 1. Check that given formula satisfies equation and initial conditions. 2. Consider another solution which is $x_1=x+x^*$, where $x$ is given formula. Then $x^*$ satisfies equation with initial conditions $x^*(0)=0, \dot{x}^*(0)=0$.